# Updating QTableView after reading whole file to QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have some newbie question. I'm not sure if I understand Model-View-Controller design pattern correctly.

Maybe I will start from describing my problem. I'm reading some data from file. This can take let's say 10 seconds and after that I present those data in the table. The question is how should I store those data? Besides `QStandardItemModel` should I have another container to which I will read data from file and use it in other threads? For example, I have `QStandardItemModel` in Gui thread and I create another container let's say `QVector`. I load data from file to `QVector` and then I move data from `QVector` to `QStandardItemModel`?

I can't use `QStandardItemModel` in other thread and read data directly from file to `QStandardItemModel` because GUI freeze as I know because `QStandardItemModel` emits signal to update view after `appendRow`.

Or maybe I should create custom model and add method to update view only when whole file is loaded into `QStandardItemModel`? `QTableView` has own container for data and it's not synchronized with the model? Is it possible/correct way?

What with situation when I read a new file?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You want to load data from file only one time or some times?

Comment: Yeah, more than one. In case of only one then I think I can share QStandardItemModel between GUI and read file thread. 
When I read new file I would like to fill model only with new data. I was thinking about setting new model for every time I read file but I think it's not nice and efficient solution.
btw. in that case how to remove memory from old QStandardItemModel?

Comment: if you take *10 seconds* to read the file into the model, I guess you have a **very big** number of rows/columns. I would suggest not loading them at once in a `QStandardItemModel`, and do some lazy loading using `QAbstractItemModel`, [`canFetchMore`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore), [`fetchMore`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore). note that this is the strategy used internally in [`QSqlQueryModel`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/sql/models/qsqlquerymodel.cpp#n190) when loading *large* models.

Comment: Take a look at [Fetch More Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html) from Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do such steps for resolve your problem:

1. When you need to load new data from file, set model for your `QTableView` in `nullptr`.
2. Fill `QStandardItemModel` (this model was the model for your `QTableView`) in non-main (non-GUI) thread with data from file.
3. Set model with data for your `QTableView` in main (GUI) thread.

Of course, the simplest way to solve your problem also may be to show for user something like this: "Data loading, please wait...", while you load data in `QStandardItemModel` in main (GUI) thread.